# Join two query's

Tags: mysql

I have this two querys, I'm trying to make a left join to get some data, but i don't success

the first query i get is

```
SELECT parte, sum(cantidad) FROM `directoscount` where deleted_at is null group by parte
```

this is the result that i have with that query and is correct

[image]

and the second is

```
select material, sum(totalStock) from lx02 group by material
```

and this is the second result

[image]

I want to make a left join and i try with something like this

```
SELECT directoscount.parte, SUM(directoscount.cantidad), lx02.material, SUM(lx02.totalStock) FROM directoscount LEFT JOIN lx02 ON directoscount.parte = lx02.material GROUP BY directoscount.parte, lx02.material
```

and the result of my query bring data to much different

[image]

Comment: Good question. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Tip for next time, use text tables instead of images for data, and consider using [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4) with sample data. Pure database questions can go on [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) too.

Answer (score 2):

You second query doesn't have  `where deleted_at is null` which make the comparison of `SUM(directoscount.cantidad)` unequal.

`SUM(lx02.totalStock)` is different in the final query because it is being counted for each `directoscount.parte`.  So for parte 486298 the last query shows a total of 2076. divide this by 346 and you get exactly 6, the number of `parte=476298` entries.

```
SELECT directoscount.parte,
       SUM(directoscount.cantidad),
       lx02.material,
       SUM(lx02.totalStock)/COUNT(directoscount.parte)
FROM directoscount
LEFT JOIN lx02
  ON directoscount.parte = lx02.material
GROUP BY directoscount.parte, lx02.material
```

Comment: I try with the answer you get me, but it throw me an error at `COUNT(directoscount)` `#1054 - Unknown column 'directoscount' in 'field list'`

Comment: I create a db-fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=838a509e8614a0c0decf5171800e246f What your answer throw me is like what you tell me, about I get exactly 6 but what i want is the first and second result joined to compare the results

Comment: Look at [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=661d6dad72be86e547e64915841a3ee8), I think its what you want. Given the directoscount and lx02 `deleted_at` aren't correlated a join won't totally work hence the union all.